# Silenium Как получить доступ к элементу если выдает ошибку "Unable to locate element"

Tags: python

Есть задача сделать автозаполнение формы на сайте, который размещен в публичном доступе, но требуется авторизация, которую я по понятным причинам предоставить не могу.
Нужно заполнить форму определенными значениями, при этом значение на сайте уже может быть заполнено, а может быть поставлен прочерк значение placeholder = "-"
Я пробовал кликнуть на элемент по имени сlass, но названия всех сlass идентичны, как и их содержание за исключением параметра value=" ", которое и нужно изменить.
Я пробовал кликнуть на элемент класса через xpath, пробовал указывать путь
краткий и полный путь, сделал пошаговое действие клик-очистка-отправка ключа, но каждый раз выходит ошибка: "element not interactable"

```html
<tbody class="css-0">
  <tr role="row" class="css-0">
    <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
      <div class="css-k008qs">Значение 1
        <p class="chakra-text css-x2vee8">*</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
      <div class="chakra-editable css-kwce8b"><span tabindex="0" class="chakra-editable__preview css-2f0ajq">91&nbsp;567,20</span><input placeholder="-" class="chakra-editable__input css-xq7e64" value="91&nbsp;567,20" hidden=""></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr role="row" class="css-0">
    <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
      <div class="css-k008qs">Значение 2
        <p class="chakra-text css-x2vee8">*</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
      <div class="chakra-editable css-kwce8b"><span tabindex="0" class="chakra-editable__preview css-2f0ajq">112&nbsp;262,00</span><input hidden="" placeholder="-" class="chakra-editable__input css-xq7e64" value="112&nbsp;262,00"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr role="row" class="css-0">
    <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
      <div class="css-k008qs">Значение 3
        <p class="chakra-text css-x2vee8">*</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
      <div class="chakra-editable css-kwce8b"><span tabindex="0" class="chakra-editable__preview css-2f0ajq">1&nbsp;728,50</span><input hidden="" placeholder="-" class="chakra-editable__input css-xq7e64" value="1&nbsp;728,50"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr role="row" class="css-0">
    <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
      <div class="css-k008qs">Значение 4
        <p class="chakra-text css-x2vee8">*</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
      <div class="chakra-editable css-kwce8b"><span tabindex="0" class="chakra-editable__preview css-2f0ajq">0,00</span><input hidden="" placeholder="-" class="chakra-editable__input css-xq7e64" value="0,00"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Мой код

```html
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'some_url'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\Python\Scripts\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
#Нажимаю на определенное значение (Работает)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div').click()
#1 страница
#Пропускаем страницу нажимаем кнопку Далее (Работает)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]').click()
#2 страница
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/input').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/input').clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/input').send_keys('12')
```

код html
в котором встречается
[image: Код]

Полный код страницы:

```html
<html lang="en" style="--chakra-ui-color-mode:light;">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Forms</title>
  <script>
    let __DEV__ = false;
  </script>
  <script type="module" crossorigin="" src="/assets/index.d279f12f.js"></script>
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/vendor.3d4bb123.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.e7b76053.css">
  <style data-emotion="css-global" data-s=""></style>
  <style data-emotion="css-global" data-s=""></style>
  <style data-emotion="css-global" data-s=""></style>
  <style data-emotion="css" data-s=""></style>
</head>

<body class="chakra-ui-light">
  <div id="root">
    <div class="css-ytjqcr">
      <div class="css-8atqhb">
        <div class="css-f7mhtb"><button type="button" class="chakra-button css-taj3dd"><span class="chakra-button__icon css-1wh2kri"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" focusable="false" class="chakra-icon css-onkibi" aria-hidden="true"><path fill="currentColor" d="M15.41 7.41L14 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L10.83 12z"></path></svg></span>На главную</button>
          <div
            class="css-1lekzkb" style="gap: 20px;">
            <p class="chakra-text css-79wky">Имя Фамилия</p><button type="button" class="chakra-button css-1dmhq2a">Выйти</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="css-0">
      <div class="css-1i71vey">
        <div class="css-uqxagj">
          <div class="css-m1kt3">
            <div class="css-1yf8e7i">
              <p class="chakra-text css-mgrz8s">4</p>
            </div>
            <p class="chakra-text css-1m4usgl">Наименование объекта</p>
          </div>
          <div class="css-19cvh75">
            <div class="chakra-stack css-1kumw4w">
              <div class="css-vn9aj9">
                <div class="css-1t3oi0e">
                  <p class="chakra-text css-151z76u">Финансирование</p>
                  <p class="chakra-text css-pmk6q4">*накопительный итог</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr aria-orientation="horizontal" class="chakra-divider css-v3w9d7">
              <div class="css-uthdbr">
                <div class="css-120nera">
                  <div class="css-146d7ys"></div>
                  <p class="chakra-text css-3sacka">План на дату отчета (2021 год)*</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="css-1d5862p">
                <div class="css-16cp454">
                  <div class="css-17hckkm">
                    <p class="chakra-text css-ykxqmn">Всего профинансировано</p>
                    <p class="chakra-text css-1c6lcpg">202222.70</p>
                  </div>
                  <div parent="[object Object]" class="css-0">
                    <p class="chakra-text css-rlof2i">Единица измерения<span class="chakra-text css-x2vee8">*</span></p>
                    <div class="chakra-select__wrapper css-12i89a3">
                      <select class="chakra-select css-lne0zh">
                        <option value="">тыс. руб.</option>
                        <option value="тыс. руб.">тыс. руб.</option>
                      </select>
                      <div class="chakra-select__icon-wrapper css-zj2dqk"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation" class="chakra-select__icon" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 1em; height: 1em; color: currentcolor;"><path fill="currentColor" d="M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z"></path></svg></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="css-13d9vo8">
                  <table role="table" class="chakra-table css-1voioz9">
                    <thead class="css-0">
                      <tr role="row" class="css-0">
                        <th class="css-1uwbmfe"></th>
                        <th class="css-1uwbmfe"></th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="css-0">
                      <tr role="row" class="css-0">
                        <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
                          <div class="css-k008qs">Значение 1
                            <p class="chakra-text css-x2vee8">*</p>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
                          <div class="chakra-editable css-kwce8b"><span tabindex="0" class="chakra-editable__preview css-2f0ajq">91&nbsp;567,20</span><input placeholder="-" class="chakra-editable__input css-xq7e64" value="91&nbsp;567,20" hidden=""></div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr role="row" class="css-0">
                        <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
                          <div class="css-k008qs">Значение 2
                            <p class="chakra-text css-x2vee8">*</p>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
                          <div class="chakra-editable css-kwce8b"><span tabindex="0" class="chakra-editable__preview css-2f0ajq">112&nbsp;262,00</span><input hidden="" placeholder="-" class="chakra-editable__input css-xq7e64" value="112&nbsp;262,00"></div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr role="row" class="css-0">
                        <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
                          <div class="css-k008qs">Значение 3
                            <p class="chakra-text css-x2vee8">*</p>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
                          <div class="chakra-editable css-kwce8b"><span tabindex="0" class="chakra-editable__preview css-2f0ajq">1&nbsp;728,50</span><input hidden="" placeholder="-" class="chakra-editable__input css-xq7e64" value="1&nbsp;728,50"></div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr role="row" class="css-0">
                        <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
                          <div class="css-k008qs">Значение 4
                            <p class="chakra-text css-x2vee8">*</p>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
                          <div class="chakra-editable css-kwce8b"><span tabindex="0" class="chakra-editable__preview css-2f0ajq">0,00</span><input placeholder="-" class="chakra-editable__input css-xq7e64" value="0,00" hidden=""></div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot class="css-0">
                      <tr role="row" class="css-0">
                        <th class="css-gtrl6i">Итого</th>
                        <th class="css-19qned7">205557.70</th>
                      </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr aria-orientation="horizontal" class="chakra-divider css-v3w9d7">
              <div class="css-uthdbr">
                <div class="css-120nera">
                  <div class="css-146d7ys"></div>
                  <p class="chakra-text css-3sacka">Факт на дату отчета (2021 год)*</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="css-1d5862p">
                <div class="css-16cp454">
                  <div class="css-17hckkm">
                    <p class="chakra-text css-ykxqmn">Всего профинансировано</p>
                    <p class="chakra-text css-1c6lcpg">114471.70</p>
                  </div>
                  <div parent="[object Object]" class="css-0">
                    <p class="chakra-text css-rlof2i">Единица измерения<span class="chakra-text css-x2vee8">*</span></p>
                    <div class="chakra-select__wrapper css-12i89a3">
                      <select class="chakra-select css-lne0zh">
                        <option value="">тыс. руб.</option>
                        <option value="тыс. руб.">тыс. руб.</option>
                      </select>
                      <div class="chakra-select__icon-wrapper css-zj2dqk"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation" class="chakra-select__icon" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 1em; height: 1em; color: currentcolor;"><path fill="currentColor" d="M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z"></path></svg></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="css-13d9vo8">
                  <table role="table" class="chakra-table css-1voioz9">
                    <thead class="css-0">
                      <tr role="row" class="css-0">
                        <th class="css-1uwbmfe"></th>
                        <th class="css-1uwbmfe"></th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="css-0">
                      <tr role="row" class="css-0">
                        <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
                          <div class="css-k008qs">Значение 1
                            <p class="chakra-text css-x2vee8">*</p>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
                          <div class="chakra-editable css-kwce8b"><span tabindex="0" class="chakra-editable__preview css-2f0ajq">91&nbsp;567,10</span><input hidden="" placeholder="-" class="chakra-editable__input css-xq7e64" value="91&nbsp;567,10"></div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr role="row" class="css-0">
                        <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
                          <div class="css-k008qs">Значение 2
                            <p class="chakra-text css-x2vee8">*</p>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
                          <div class="chakra-editable css-kwce8b"><span tabindex="0" class="chakra-editable__preview css-2f0ajq">21&nbsp;941,20</span><input hidden="" placeholder="-" class="chakra-editable__input css-xq7e64" value="21&nbsp;941,20"></div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr role="row" class="css-0">
                        <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
                          <div class="css-k008qs">Значение 3
                            <p class="chakra-text css-x2vee8">*</p>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
                          <div class="chakra-editable css-kwce8b"><span tabindex="0" class="chakra-editable__preview css-2f0ajq">963,40</span><input hidden="" placeholder="-" class="chakra-editable__input css-xq7e64" value="963,40"></div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr role="row" class="css-0">
                        <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
                          <div class="css-k008qs">Значение 4
                            <p class="chakra-text css-x2vee8">*</p>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">
                          <div class="chakra-editable css-kwce8b"><span tabindex="0" class="chakra-editable__preview css-2f0ajq">0,00</span><input hidden="" placeholder="-" class="chakra-editable__input css-xq7e64" value="0,00"></div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot class="css-0">
                      <tr role="row" class="css-0">
                        <th class="css-gtrl6i">Итого</th>
                        <th class="css-19qned7">114471.70</th>
                      </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr aria-orientation="horizontal" class="chakra-divider css-v3w9d7">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="css-gg4vpm"><button type="button" class="chakra-button css-1sovv3u">Назад</button><button type="button" class="chakra-button css-1sovv3u">Далее</button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  

</body></html>
```

Comment: Дайте ссылку на проект

Comment: @ProgerOffline Форма находится в открытом доступе, но требует авторизацию, которую я предоставить не могу. Добавил полный код страницы в конец вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте получать сначала фрагмент таблицы, а потом все input-элементы которые есть в нем, и сохранить их в виде спика. Далее просто ссылаться к ним по интексам.

```
# Поулчаем фрагмент таблицы с нужынми input'ами
table = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("tbody.css-0")

# Получаем список все input'ов в фрагменте таблицы
input_list = table.find_elements_by_css_selector("input")
```

Ну, а дальше вам решать, что с ними делать.

Comment: Да, я так тоже пробовал, только искал по другому имени класса . Я так и не нашел ответа как, к примеру, кликнуть на первый элемент  element="d1ca3f53-f134-447d-a9a6-262b82c567b9"
table [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="cd413a8e6c62c1485ba4935fcc043671", element="d1ca3f53-f134-447d-a9a6-262b82c567b9")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="cd413a8e6c62c1485ba4935fcc043671", element="23094a88-1464-477a-aadd-213a5f437bb7")>]
Исп. 2-й комнды
'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_css_selector'

Comment: В данном случае у нас список элементов, кликнуть на первый элемент можно вот так input_list[0].click()

Comment: Ошибок никаких не выдает, но при этом последующих действий с элементом не свершает. Попробую пойти иначе и извлечь текст из элемента, чтобы посмотреть на какой конкретно элемент он ссылается. Надеюсь, это поможет. Вернусь сюда с ответом

Comment: Получил значение элемента ,но брал другой CSS                                                  
table = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"td.css-11hihop") далее table[1].text но получаю ошибку от которой просто теряюсь) Как я могу кликать на элемент из "шапки", если я выбрал конкретный элемент. В общем все очень странно...
Message: element click intercepted: Element <td role="gridcell" class="css-11hihop">...</td> is not clickable at point (919, 48). Other element would receive the click: <div class="css-f7mhtb">...</div>

Comment: Пробовал  table = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.css-11hihop")
fedbudg = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//tbody[@class=’css-0’]/descendant::span[text()=table[1].text]")   но все равно не выходит. Ладно, видимо, пора сдаться) Возможно, что кто-то позже поможет или дойдет как сделать. Спасибо Вам!